# Java - Error trying to print an array made of 2 appended arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am studying in prevision of my exam of Software Programming. Here I am trying to append 2 arrays but what I get printed is: 
`[I@17dfafd1`

here is the code:

```
package examPreparation2014;
public class FirstExercise {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] first = {1,2,3};
        int[] second = {4,5,6};

        System.out.print(FirstExercise.concatenator(first, second));
    }
    public static int[] concatenator(int[] first, int[] second){
        int[] concatenatedArray = new int[first.length + second.length];

        for (int i = 0; i<first.length ; i++){
            concatenatedArray[i] = first[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<second.length; i++){
            concatenatedArray[i+first.length] = second[i];
        }
        return concatenatedArray;
    }
}
```

PS: this is an exam on paper, therefore I cannot import libraries :-)

Comment: What do you expect to be printed and why?

Comment: {1,2,3,4,5,6} but thanks to rgettman I understood my error.

Comment: Always question your expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are Objects too, but they don't override [`Object`'s `toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

> In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

That explains the strange-looking output you've received.

Try [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-):

> The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space).

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(FirstExercise.concatenator(first, second)));
```

Comment: thanks now I understood my error!! I am a Ruby on Rails developer switching to java is TERRIBLE!!

Comment: is Arrays.toString available only on Java 8?

Comment: Available since Java 5.  `Since:
1.5`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it's printing the default implementation of [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) of object class.

Simply use for each loop to print all the values of the array.

```
for (int i : concatenator(first, second)) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

---

A simpler way to append two arrays using [org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html)

```
int[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

Comment: @JackScotti what the actual issue. your haven't look at the your actual problem statement. I added it just for an addition if you are interested.